# Final URL (after all redirects) using apache HttpClient

Tags: java, httpclient

How do I get the final URL of a Http request when I use `HttpMethod.setFollowRedirects(true)`. I am using apache Httpclient - `GetMethod`.

Comment: Would this be HttpClient 3 or 4? They have significant API differences.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `method.getURI()`, or as suggested by Stephen - `method.getPath()` ?

Comment: Certainly the getPath() method is documented as returning the path used *after* redirections have been performed.  The getURI() method doesn't say one way or the other, but it would be a reasonable assumption that it behaves the same way as getPath().